# Test through the roof

Tags: idiomatic-language

what is the meaning of "test through the roof" in this sentence?
"She's gonna test through the roof." "She" is a ballet dancer who is going to audition a group of people who want to join a dance company. The sentence comes from the first episode of The Big Leap.

Answer (score 3):

The idiom *test through the roof* means to be put to some test and achieve great success.

Here are some examples:

> [They] will have to sift through a mountain of information to find the true value of every player. There will be "workout warriors" that test through the roof and raise their stock just as there will be "flops" whose stock will drop, simply because they don't run as fast or aren't as tall as advertised.

["The NFL Combine: A former Player's Perspective"](https://www.chiefs.com/news/the-nfl-combine-a-former-player-s-perspective-9599924)

> So why wasn't [the film] released in theaters?...'The movie tested reasonably well, but Miramax needed it to test through the roof. It's not that kind of movie.'

["BURIED TREASURE" - Chicago Tribune](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-2000-08-10-0008100071-story.html)

> “The pilot did not test through the roof, it didn’t do great and NBC was on the fence about putting it on their schedule,”

["‘The West Wing’ Reunion" - Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/west-wing-reunion-at-atx-901792/)

> "This was a dark movie and it shouldn’t have been tested in those places. Audience test-screenings are blunt instruments. You hear about things that 'test through the roof' and no one goes to see them. Boogie Nights tested terribly. But New Line left that movie alone and let it be its dark self."

["How One Disastrous Test Screening Ruined Ryan Phillippe's 54"](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-One-Disastrous-Test-Screening-Ruined-Ryan-Phillippe-54-69818.html)

As you can see, this phrase is often used in a context where *test* means "to be assigned a standing or evaluation on the basis of **[screen]** tests" ([Screen test - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_test)) as *Merriam-Webster* defines the term: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test

Answer (score 1):

["Through the roof"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/through+the+roof) is an idiom meaning "a large amount" or "a high level." I **almost always** see it used in the expression "*go* through the roof" meaning "to *increase* to a very high level."

"Test through the roof" is not a phrase I recognize, nor would most people, I don't think. But in context we can infer that it means "she will do a lot of testing" or possibly "she will test to a very high standard." It is not very clear which one is intended; perhaps knowing the context of how many dancers are auditioning would help.